# Is it possible to add list of types to generic interface?

Tags: c#

I want to create an interface such as...

```
interface IRepository<params T>
{
    T GetAll();
}

class PersonRepository : IRepository<Employees,Students>
{
    Employees GetAll();
    Students GetAll();
}
```

So clearly I know that the concrete implementation is impossible but is there any way to take a multi entity repostitory and create some super base interface?

Comment: I believe it's not possible in general. But, there are built-in classes Func<T>, Func<T,T1>, Func<T,T1,T2>, .... I hope you got the idea :)

Comment: Your repository example isn't a very good one, because I'm sure everyone is thinking why not just implement two repositories?

Comment: Super base interface sounds like a scary, slippery slope. Favor composition over inheritance.

Comment: Maybe it would better to add a new class, smth like EntityManager, which will serve all operations on required entity types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's something possible:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string EmpName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.EmpName;
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string StudName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.StudName;
        }
    }

    public class Other
    {
        public int TestField { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.TestField.ToString();
        }
    }

    public interface IRepository<T>
    {
        List<T> GetAll();
    }

    public class PersonRepository : IRepository<Employee>, IRepository<Student>, IRepository<Other>
    {
        List<Student> IRepository<Student>.GetAll()
        {
            return new List<Student> { new Student { StudName = "test2" } };
        }

        List<Other> IRepository<Other>.GetAll()
        {
            return new List<Other> { new Other { TestField = 42 } };
        }

        List<Employee> IRepository<Employee>.GetAll()
        {
            return new List<Employee> { new Employee { EmpName = "test1" } };
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PersonRepository d = new PersonRepository();

            // Returns "test1"
            Console.WriteLine(((IRepository<Employee>)d).GetAll()[0]);

            // Returns "test2"
            Console.WriteLine(((IRepository<Student>)d).GetAll()[0]);

            // Returns 42
            Console.WriteLine(((IRepository<Other>)d).GetAll()[0]);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you have to explicitly cast your class so your application can known which `GetAll()` method to call.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for, im sure it was floating around in my head somewhere I just couldnt see it. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a flawed design approach to me and is not possible since methods cannot vary by return types only and the language does not support lists of type parameters in that fashion.

You could implement a common base class and store them in a List of the base class (`List<Person> personRepository;`). Then fetching the members of a given type is simple with a Linq extension, i.e. `List<Students> = personRepository.OfType<Student>().ToList();`.

Answer (score -2):

No not at all, but you can do this:

```
// base interface for entity types
interface IEntity 
{
}

class Employees : IEntity
{
}

class Students : IEntity
{
}

interface IRepository<T1, T2> where T1:IEntity where T2:IEntity
{
    T1 GetAll();
    T2 GetAll();
}

class PersonRepository : IRepository<Employees,Students>
{
    Employees GetAll();
    Students GetAll();
}
```

The number of type parameters cannot be varied dynamically unfortunately.

Alternatively you could do this:

```
// base interface for entity types
interface IEntity 
{
}

class Employees : IEntity
{
}

class Students : IEntity
{
}

interface IRepository 
{
    RegisterEntities(IEnumerable<IEntity> entities);

    IEnumerable<IEntity> GetAll();
}

class PersonRepository : IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<IEntity> GetAll() 
    {
       // Todo
    }
    }
```

This would mean you can add Employees and Students to the same repository, as they share a base interface. Later you can extract them and put common fields on the IEntity (e.g. Name, Age) for easy access.

Comment: Have you actually compiled this?

Comment: In your first example the IRepository interface won't compile as you've got two methods that only differ in their return type.